# "Type comparisons" in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, types, comparison

I'm writing a program where I have to test if elements of a list are of a certain type. The list (z, found below) can get large and I could test the standard way:

```
for l in z:
  typeL = type(l)
  if typeL == complex or typeL == float:
    #evaluate suite
  elif typeL == list:
    #evaluate different suite
```

Or, I can do the following:

```
for l in z:
  lTemp = l*0
  if lTemp == 0:
    #evaluate suite
  elif lTemp == []:
    #evaluate different suite
```

My question is, which method is faster, more efficient, or preferred? Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: can you add some hints, what you try to achieve? It is unusual (in python) that you need such a differentiation by type.

Comment: It's for a more comprehensive sqrt function than the Python standard.

Comment: Something like `cmath.sqrt`? Or `numpy.sqrt`?

Comment: @larsmans Well, the basic functionality, yes. Although, I'm trying to add a bit more. I have to mention, however, I haven't used the sqrt from the numpy library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

- Explicit is better than implicit.
- Simple is better than complex

So if you want to compare types, you should get types and compare them.
Clearer method is using `isinstance method` that is accepting tuple-of-types argument. So your code may look like this:

```
for l in z:
  if isinstance(l,(complex,float)):
    #evaluate suite
  elif isinstance(l,list):
    #evaluate different suite
```

Also isinstance is compatible  with ABC metaclasses, so you could be more straight and clear in your choises:

```
from numbers import Number
from collections import Iterable

for l in z:
  if isinstance(l,Number):
    #evaluate suite
  elif isinstance(l,Iterable):
    #evaluate different suite
```

**UPD:** Answering to a question in commentary about perfomance, you should remember, that [**premature optimization is the root of all evil**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). When your program will work, you could analize it and find where the perfomance actually falls. Next you could optimize it in python, rewrite in cython or C, could use another implementation, etc. But while you are coding in python you must respect what is better for python code.

Comment: Bonus feature for using `isinstance()`: works with subclasses.

Comment: +1 for showing the clean way of doing this. I'd give you a +2 if I could; I'd never seen the `isinstance` tuple-syntax before!

Comment: Though actually, I think "explicit is better than implicit" is a more appropriate rule here :)

Comment: @Odomontois Nice. I didn't know about `isinstance()`. Although Wouldn't he code I presented (in the second code block) be faster than a function call?

Comment: Why would it be faster? `*` has to do the type lookup anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, what you try to do, but since you have the two implementations (nearly) ready, you should benchmark them with *your* data, to decide which implementation is faster in *your* case.

I would be surprised to see a big  difference in performance, only if **#evaluate suite** is a very cheap operation.

From a **readability** or **maintainability** point of view I would prefer the first one. The trick to do `lTemp = l*0` is not very intuitive to me.

Comment: I opt for `lTemp = l*0` since if `l` is a complex or float, `l*0 == 0` will evaluate as `True`, and accordingly, may be faster. The same goes if `l` is a list.